# Summing up each group of a Table in SSRS VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am working on SSRS reports. I have a table having group i.e.

[image]

But I want this kind of table as a result:

[image]

That is summing the Age Total in each group.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asma, use for the group you created the group footer. inserting the age total there will create the relevant sum.